# Calling replace on replacement String in replaceAll() method

Tags: java, regex, text-processing

It seems like this should work, but it doesn't... I'm trying to call the replace() method on the replacement String passed to the replaceAll() method.

For example I tried to get rid of any commas inside double quotes with this code:

```
String string = "\"Thu, Sep 6, 2018 10:00 AM\"";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(\"[^\"]+\")", "$1".replace(",", "")));
```

And the result is the same string: `"Thu, Sep 6, 2018 10:00 AM"` when I was hoping for `"Thu Sep 6 2018 10:00 AM"`

I've looked over the documentation for String.replaceAll() and Matcher.replaceAll() and I still can't figure out why this doesn't work.  Can anyone help me undertand?

Let me emphasize that I'm curious to know WHY this doesn't work - I'm not interested in solutions, I have already figured out an alternative.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling .replace on "$1", rather than the result of the replaceAll. Close the bracket of the replaceAll call and call the .replace method on that.

try

`System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(\"[^\"]+\")", "$1").replace(",", ""))`

Answer (score 0):

just change the closing bracket place and it will work :

```
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(\"[^\"]+\")", "$1").replace(",", ""))
```